# how to call a function from a c++ class inside a python program

Tags: python, c++, python-bindings

Class ***test*** has a member function ***check*** which is a cpp program , How can i call that function inside an independent python program. c++ python binding (did not understand it)

Comment: Start from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: It could be using RPC call

Comment: You can use PyBind11, it has a simple interface.